# Рабочий стол на несколько мониторов

Tags: delphi

Кто знает, как можно в ОС Windows расширить рабочий стол на несколько мониторов, и как с ними работать (апи функции Delphi).

Необходимо, чтобы окно одного приложения было на разных мониторах, но на одном рабочем столе.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если драйвер видеокарты позволяет, то расширение на несколько мониторов делается в свойствах экрана. Там нужно проставить галочки в нужных местах.

В Delphi в модуле Unit есть свойство Screen, которое в свою очередь имеет свойства MonitorCount и Monitors[Index: Integer]: TMonitor. Обычно их достаточно, чтобы работать с несколькими экранами.

Например, чтобы растянуть форму на выбранный монитор:

```
if Screen.MonitorCount > 1 then
begin
    form.Left:=Screen.Monitors[n].Left;
    form.Top:=Screen.Monitors[n].Top;
    form.Width:=Screen.Monitors[n].Width;
    form.Height:=Screen.Monitors[n].Height;
end
```

где n - это номер выбранного монитора. Подробнее про поддержку мониторов в Windows: [Multiple Display Monitors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145071(v=VS.85).aspx).

Comment: А как можно создать виртуальный монитор и расширить на него рабочий стол??????